# translation in qt on symbian

Tags: qt, translation, symbian, qt-quick

I have a simple Qt app which is using QTranslator. Part of the code is like:

```
QTranslator* translator = new QTranslator;

qDebug()<<"Translating: "<<translator->load(QString("inter_sk"));

app->installTranslator(translator);
```

QTranslator is loading fine when I build my project and run it on Simulator

The same app build and deployed to real Symbian device (C7) is not working properly - translator is not loading. I dont change my inter_sk.qm file so I suppose it somehow is not deployed to the device.

An guesses???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must bundle the translations files with your application so they get deployed on device.

You can add :

```
translations.sources = *.qm
DEPLOYMENT += translations
```

to your .pro